# OpenID delegation seems not to work with OpenID Authentication plugin for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

I've just installed the OpenID Authentication plugin because I'd like to use it for my projects, but as I tried to login using my blog url I got the first error message:

"Sorry, the OpenID server couldn't be found"

Does the plugin support delegation?

If yes, what is wrong with my blog? (I use wp-openid with XRDS-Simple)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sure does support that.  Works fine with my blog: beautifulpixel.com

Does it find the OpenID server for that one?  If not check your head tags.

BTW, http://thewinespies.com/ runs this plugin for OpenID, so you can run a sanity check there if you like.

Comment: Your blog url does work! Now I'm sure that the problem is with my blog, but I have no idea what the problem is..
Does anyone use wp-openid?

Comment: how about you post a link to your blog?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post it.. http://www.mcforge.net
I can't still authenticate using "mcforge.net" as my OpenID Identifier while if I try to copy and paste the home page code to another url (in a static page) I can authenticate using that url. You can see it at: mcforge.net/openid2.html

Comment: I'm sure that the problem isn't OpenID Authentication plugin because this site neither accept "mcforge.net" as an OpenID Identifier.

Comment: You don't have anything in the headers of your blog to serve as an openid delegate.  They just arent there. http://netevil.org/blog/2007/06/howto-set-yourself-up-with-an-openid

Comment: Thank you very much! I've resolved: I had a problem with WP Super Cache!